# Iterate over map keys using Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a nested map `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ...>`

How would I use Java 8 lambdas to navigate over map. Here possible imperative solution:

```
Object getObjectWithKey(String key) { // key = "parent.parent1.parent1.1"
    Map head = mainMap;

    for (String k in key.split(".")){
      head = head.get(k);
    }

    return (Object) head;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use lambdas? Lambdas are syntax sugar for anonymous classes, but in your case they do not apply.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez just for exercising purpose

Comment: I don't understand this at all. How many levels of nesting does this map have?

Comment: @PaulBoddington can have unlimited, think of a json document

Comment: I think you mean using java-8 *streams* (with or without lambdas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, I do not understand the need for this at all. A json document should be converted to a Java object of an appropriate type, not some highly nested `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ...>>>`.

Even without lambdas, this is going to require unchecked casts from `Object` to `Map<String, Object>`, and it could easily fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`.

Adding lambdas on top of this adds an extra level of complexity because the variables used in a lambda body have to be effectively final, whereas `head` is re-assigned at each stage. You can get around this by using an array of length 1.

The resulting code is hideous (and I do **not** recommend this), but it achieves what you ask for:

```
Object[] head = {mainMap};
Stream.of(key.split(".")).forEach(s -> {
    head[0] = ((Map<String, ?>) head[0]).get(s);
});
return head[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are appropriate when you need to provide an instance of any interface that has a single method, like `Runnable`.

For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running on thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
}).start();
```

Can be converted to:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("Running on thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
}).start();
```

Or even:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Running on thread: " + Thread.currentThread())).start();
```

In your case, I do not see where you need such instance.